# PHP bulk emails without cron job

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, email, cron

I'm currently building a wordpress plugin for a charity, and am wondering what my options are for sending out bulk emails. They have an event once a year, and before the event, they need to send out 600-1,200+ emails, from a list of emails in their database. I was thinking about building an emailing system, with a queue, but since they only really need to send stuff out one month out of the year, a cron job seems a bit excessive. Are there anyways to create a cron, and then remove it after the action is complete? Are there any alternatives to a cron for automating tasks? I'm just brain storming at this point, so any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: For a Non-Profit you might want to consider using a commercial service (MailChimp) .. which is free if you have a subscriber list <2000 and send out fewer than 12000 emails in a month.

Comment: I would utilize Mailchimp API or something similar.

Comment: Are the emails personalised? If not, you could send a small batch of emails with BCC fields populated with a hundred or so at a time, and can be done from any mail client.

Comment: You could use [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) which is the transactional email platform made by MailChimp. I highly recommend using a transactional email platform instead of sending mass mail via the server, which is likely to get you blacklisted quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I'll checkout mail chip and mandrill.